# how to add billing adress and card number on my website by Authorize.Net

Tags: wordpress, authorize.net

I need these fields for  Authorize.Net on the checkout page (see img).
I'm using plugin WooCommerce Authorize.Net Gateway (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/authorizenet-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/).
But it shows these fields like this (see image 2) and does not show the billing address.
How can I do what I need?

[image: img №1]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to add billing address to the payment form hosted by Authorize.Net. You would need to proceed as follow:

- Log into the Authorize.Net Merchant Interface (Production:https://login.authorize.net/ ; Sandbox:https://logintest.authorize.net/).
- Click Account.
- Select Payment Form (under Transaction Format Settings).
- Payment Form – Form Fields
- Specify the fields that may be viewed and edited by a customer, and required to complete a transaction

The following article has more details: [Adding Information to the Hosted Payment Form and Receipt Pages](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Adding-Information-to-the-Hosted-Payment-Form-and-Receipt-Pages)